# Accessing DOM node and functions bound to the underlying class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, this

I'm defining a callback function in a Object and I'll like to access the DOM node as the item is clicked but I also want to access the functions of my underlying class. 
I don't know if that makes sense, here's some code to prove my point:

```
class App extends Component{

   state = {
     nodeColor: ''
   }

   componentDidMount(){
        this.options = {
          eventClick: function(){
            console.log(this);
            //processDOMnode(this);
          }
        }
   }

   processDOMnode = (node) => {
     console.log(node);
     this.setState({ nodeColor: node.color });
   }

}
```

The nodes are spawned by a third party library so I can't directly get a reference to the element being clicked without using accessing `this` in the `eventClick` callback - but as I said, I would like to access methods like `setState` and i can't do that inside `eventClick` because of scoping.

Did I miss something basic?

Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/0x03w3070n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eventClick: function(event)` and bind the event listener to your component `this.options.eventClick.bind(this)`. Then, you can access the node using something like this `event.target`.

Here is a complete example:

```
class App extends Component{

   state = {
     nodeColor: ''
   }

   componentDidMount(){
        this.options = {
          eventClick: function(event){
            this.processDOMnode(event.target);
          }
        }
   }

   processDOMnode = (node) => {
     this.setState({ nodeColor: node.color });
   }

   render() {
       return <button onClick={this.options.eventClick.bind(this)}>Click Me</button>
   }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, almost - problem is I can't control the onClick by using `bind(this`). I added a codesandbox link using the library: https://codesandbox.io/s/0x03w3070n

Comment: @John You can bind the component to the function using something like this:  `eventClick: (function(event) {.....}).bind(this)`, it will be probably more readable if you use a named function instead of an anonymous function

Comment: @John It seems that the event passed to `eventClick` is not the actual click event, you can do this instead https://codesandbox.io/s/zn6rpj7vo4

Comment: omg it worked, thanks a lot!! cant believe i didn't try to do that earlier. some misunderstandings regarding `this` I think